# CMS migration challenges : Dotnet Nuke to Sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, migration, sitecore, dotnetnuke

I'm having a project where I have to migrate the data and UI from DotNet Nuke to Sitecore, for implementing 508 compliance.
Now my understanding is both share dotnet as underlying platform, so migration issues will be few. But I'm getting not much info. related with site core online.

So, does anybody here have experinece of such migration?

Need help regarding this, specificallly looking for content storage and technical architecture  and potential I may encounter.

Thanks

Comment: You better start learning Sitecore first and understand the principles, before trying to do a migration. Or hire one of the Sitecore specialists.

Comment: You really should post a question that can be answered here, this post currently isn't SO worthy

Comment: It is NOT that just because both CMS'es were built using the .NET framework you won't find yourself having any troubles migrating. Generally the architecture of CMS'es can be different and solutions might differ based on this fact. This is not a question, we can not really help you on this now.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, it is going to be very complicated. Although both are based on .Net, their underlying architecture is completely different. You should consider either getting sitecore training or hire someone who understands both systems.
You'd go out migrating just like any other app migration. But the time it takes to do a proper migration depends on how much you know about both the cmses.

- build sitecore information architecture based on new requirements
- export content from DNN site in xml format based on sitecore template structure
- import content into Sitecore site from the extracted xml files